# Pycharm: Cannot see print() how do I run feature files in Python Console?

Tags: python, pycharm, console, python-behave

I'm confused with the answers I found so I created a separate question :(

I am currently using Pycharm Community Edition and I am trying to run my feature file using console but I am not sure how to. I have a `print()` statement but I cannot see the contents of the variable as it is not printing in the terminal. How do I run the feature file in console?

When I run in terminal, all of my steps are passed. But I cannot see any `print()` statement being returned. :/

I tried setting up the run configuration but I am getting an error :/
[image]

Here is a sample of what I'm doing

```
Scenario: Scenario title
    Given user just wants to print please
```

`.py`

```
@given("user just want to print please")
def step_impl(context):
    baseURL = "someUrl"
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    context.login = login(context.driver)
    context.driver.get(baseURL)
    context.login.userLogin('someEmail@email.com', 'somePassword')
    print("Hello")
```

Output: (No "Hello")

[image]

After pointing the working directory to steps folder
[image]

Comment: Running Python-Behave files is a feature exclusive to PyCharm Professional edition ([see the icon on the upper right corner in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-behave.html)). Since you say you're using PyCharm community you have to upgrade to preofessional or use an external tool to use the behave files.

Comment: Your question isn't entierly clear and you also didn't include the stacktrace as text, so the question doesn't have a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But looking at the screenshot I'd say you're using the wrong venv or didn't activate it.

Answer (score 0):

The error at the bottom says you don't have a working directory. Create a working directory and try again.

Comment: Hello @Lyrics I tried doing that as well but I am still encountering an error. :/ Or did I do it correctly? I updated the post above with the screenshot